# Handling stream and exceptions in Springs HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring

I've made a custom spring HttpMessageConverter, in order to create and output csv from a rest controller.
I.e. the converter is registered to handle the class type that is returned from the controller.

I use the supercsv library/framework to generate the actual csv, and therefore have a CsvMapWriter using the stream from the body of the HttpOutputMessage provided in the writeInternal overwritten method:

```
    protected void writeInternal(MyType myObject, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody());
    ICsvMapWriter mapWriter = new CsvMapWriter(oswriter,CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
```

I then go on to use the mapWriter to write the csv lines directly to the stream, e.g.

```
try{
    mapWriter.writeHeader(transactionHeader);
    mapWriter.write(transactionLevelMap, transactionHeader, getTransactionInfoProcessors());
} finally {
    if (mapWriter != null) {        
        mapWriter.close();      
    }
}
```

Since the writing - and csv map processing - can throw exceptions, I wrap the code with a try-finally, as a "standard approach" when dealing with resources like streams.

The problem is, that when the thrown exception bubbles up through the call chain, and is being picked up by the spring error handling mechanism - that wants to return a http status 500 to the client, indicating a server error, I get the following dump:

```
WARN 3208 --- [ qtp32193376-20] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : Could not send response error 500
```

I assume it is due to the fact, that I've just closed the stream from the HttpOutputMessage, which Spring now want to use for writing the error status etc.

That makes sense, but my question now is:
Should i NOT close the stream in the "finally" clause, when an exception is being thrown? (And only close it, when I now that all processing went well)

I.e. can I assume that Spring will take care of the resource deallocation once it is done with it, when it uses it for the error handling?